# Scanner HasNextLine always returns false

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm facing this weird problem with Scanner.hasNextLine().
I'm not used with the Scanner class but I'm used to use Scanner.hasNextLine() as a condition for a loop to get continuously user's input but in this part of code it always returns false !

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    Scanner ssc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Client cli = new Client();
    cli.HLO();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadMessage(cli));//Thread that asks user for input using Scanner and closing it then
    t.start();
    boolean b = ssc.hasNextLine();
    while (true) {
        b = ssc.hasNextLine();
        System.out.println(b);
        if (b) {
            s = ssc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("you wrote" + s);
            cli.dp.setData(s.getBytes());
            cli.ds.send(cli.dp);
        }
    }
}
```

and as is an input I only have a loop of lines with the word false

Does anybody have an idea why it behaves so?

**EDIT:** Seems that the errors comes froms HLO function that uses another Scanner I removed it and it words properly now.

Comment: Why reenter the loop if `hasNextLine` is false?  What do the client and `ThreadMessage` thread do?

Comment: I dont see a problem in the code...I am able to run it succcessfully

Comment: @MikeSamuel I added the code of ThreadMessage and the body of the client class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `.hasNext()` method instead of using the `.hasNextLine()` method.
You are having problems because the `.hasNextLine()` **method returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner**. But the `.hasNext()` method returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Same result if only return false i'll add this detail in my first port

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have multiple Scanner(System.in) instances in a code which is touched by several people.

If one of those instances call "**close**", it will closed for all and the file is not reopened.

After the call to close hasNextLine() always will return false.